# Problem discovering control handles \ spy++

Tags: python, controls, mouseevent, simulate, spy

I use SPY++ to find out control handles, usually it works, it seems that on some application it doesn't work. For example, on the calc.exe in WIN7 i can find out each digit control handle (and simulate a press on it), in WIN10 calc, i cannot find any control handle at all except from the main window.
can anyone please help me?
thank you

Comment: can you elaborate on which python version you are using as well as versions of other modules. Also, please add an example code to show the current functionality